# Scroll-lock/ You click->You can scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Sorry, this is maybe the worst title ever but i do not know how to call it otherwise.

Example: A user is clicking on a button and only afterwards he can scroll down the page. Before that, he can not scroll down by any means.

I only started to code like 2 months ago. Iam not a pro :D

thanks a lot and have a great winter!

Comment: You're looking for `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden;` at start and `overflow:auto;` when you need to enable scroll. You can achieve this by using CSS itself

### DEMO

```css
.button{
  padding:2px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:red;
  color:white;  
}
input#mycheck{
  display:none;
}
div.inner{
  height:100px;
  margin-top:10px;
  background:yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
}
input:checked ~ div.inner{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <label class="button" for="mycheck">enable scrolling</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" />
  <div class="inner">
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
    enable me first <br/>
  </div>
  </div>
```